# R: How to run a custom function after group_by using group_map?

Tags: r

Given that, i have a dataframe as below:

```
dt <- data.frame(year = sample(c(2000:2019),100,replace = T ),
                 month = sample(c(1:12),100,replace = T ),
                 paitent_ID = sample(c(1:50),100,replace = T ),
                 state = sample(c(1:10),100,replace = T ) )
```

and i need to apply the below function to this dataset after `group by` and **sort**:

```
newState <- function(dt){

  dt["new"]= dt[0,"state"]*3 
  dt

}
```

So, this function is supposed to add a new column called `new` to each group.

Here is the group_by:

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% 
 group_by(paitent_ID) %>%
 group_map(  ~ .x %>%
               arrange( year,month)) %>%
 group_map( ~ .x %>%
              newState())
```

when i run the code, it complains with:

```
Error in UseMethod("group_split") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_split' applied to an object of class "list"
```

Comment: Do you have to use `group_map` and this is a simplified example, or is this the actual task? The reason I ask is that this could be done with just mutate rather than group_map. Sidenote, if you want a single dataframe back with the results from all the groups rbinded together, you'd want to use `group_modify` instead of `group_map`.

Comment: Look at the output you get after your first `group_map`: it's a list of data frames, not a single data frame. `group_map` expects to work on one grouped data frame, which you no longer have

Comment: I think this should do what you want (R indices start at 1, not 0) `dt %>% 
  group_by(paitent_ID) %>% 
  arrange(year, month) %>% 
  mutate(new = state[1]*3)`

Comment: To add a column, you usually use a mutate(). "Columns" aren't group bound in a retangular tibble. But a column value can be calculated taking a group as reference, without any map. Maybe you need a tribble.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan it works well, but i need to call the function and `mutate(new = newState() )` does not work. Could you please remove your comment, so i can ask a few questions.

Comment: You might have better luck switching to tidyeval in order to add columns by custom functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @André Oliveira mentions in the comments, it is recommended to use `mutate` for adding a column. However, it is possible to do so with `group_modify` after making some small changes to your function.

```
newState <- function(dt, groupvars){

  dt["new"]= dt[1,"state"]*3 
  dt

}

dt %>% 
  group_by(paitent_ID) %>% 
  arrange(year, month) %>% 
  group_modify(newState) %>% 
  ungroup

# # A tibble: 100 x 5
#    paitent_ID  year month state   new
#         <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
#  1          1  2006     5     3     9
#  2          2  2012    12     3     9
#  3          3  2013    11     8    24
#  4          3  2014    10     1    24
#  5          3  2019     5     6    24
#  6          4  2006     7     5    15
#  7          4  2006     7     2    15
#  8          5  2003     8     8    24
#  9          7  2015    12     2     6
# 10          7  2017     8    10     6
```

And a more conventional approach

```
dt %>% 
  group_by(paitent_ID) %>% 
  arrange(year, month) %>% 
  mutate(new = state[1]*3)
```

Comment: what does `...` mean in the `function(dt, ...)`?

Comment: Nothing. `group_modify` requires the function to have at least two arguments, so I had to add one even though it doesn't do anything. Changed from `...` to a more obviously-named second argument. If you were using the value of the grouping variable in the function, the second argument is how you would access it.